# The use of "by (verb)-ing" to state a reason

Tags: phrase-usage, gerunds

> Great good luck sometimes touches a person at least once. It touched me. A book he wrote became a best-seller in 16 countries. I bought a house on the beach. My dream had come true.

These sentences are taken from "Dreams Do Come True" by Jim Bishop.

Someone asked me a question concerning it. The question is as "Why did the boy become rich?" If I answer this question by using "by *verb*-ing" in the following way, is it acceptable or grammatical ?

> Ans: The boy became rich by writing a book which became a best-seller in 16 countries.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically it's fine, although semantically it could be improved.

When the question is "***why***", you should be able to start your answer with "***because...***"  In other words, the question is about the *reason* or the *cause*, not the *manner* (of becoming rich).

The use of "*by {noun}*" or "*by {gerund}*" explains the ***how***, not the ***why***.

If you wanted to involve the book writing in your answer, you *could* write/say

> The boy became rich *because* he wrote a book which...

Those a subtle nuances and are often overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the construction "by verb-ing" is grammatical. Also, your answer is well written and grammatical too. There are no changes I would recommend.